# Tkinter: Window Resizing is Slow

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter application that hosts a tkinter Grid of ttk buttons with icons within a tkinter Frame.

Whenever I try to resize the window however, it is incredibly slow to respond. I have included how the frame responds to window size configuration and the base code that generates the board.

```
def resize_image(self, event):
    new_width = int(self.root.winfo_width() / (self.col_size*1.4))
    new_height = int(self.root.winfo_height() / (self.row_size*1.4))
    square_dim = min(new_width, new_height)
    self.image_dict = {}
    for row_index in range(self.row_size):
        for col_index in range(self.col_size):
            self.image_dict[(row_index, col_index)] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f"img/{self.check_names[row_index*self.row_size + col_index]}").resize((square_dim, square_dim)))
            self.button_dict[(row_index, col_index)].configure(image = self.image_dict[(row_index, col_index)])
    #Create & Configure frame 
    self.frame=Frame(self.root)
    self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

    self.button_dict = {}
    self.autotracking_labels = {}

def generate_card(self, row_size, col_size, seedname=None, event=None):
    self.root.geometry(f"{64*row_size}x{64*col_size}")
    Grid.rowconfigure(self.root, 0, weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(self.root, 0, weight=1)

    #Create & Configure frame 
    self.frame=Frame(self.root)
    self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

    self.button_dict = {}
    self.autotracking_labels = {}

    #Create a (rows x columns) grid of buttons inside the frame
    for row_index in range(row_size):
        Grid.rowconfigure(self.frame, row_index, weight=1)
        for col_index in range(col_size):
            Grid.columnconfigure(self.frame, col_index, weight=1)
            self.set_style(f"bnormal{row_index}{col_index}.TButton", background="black", bordercolor="#333333", highlightthickness=10, padding=0)
            self.button_dict[(row_index, col_index)] = ttk.Button(self.frame, image = self.images[row_index*self.row_size + col_index], takefocus=False, style=f'bnormal{row_index}{col_index}.TButton')
            self.button_dict[(row_index, col_index)].grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
            self.button_dict[(row_index, col_index)].configure(command = lambda row_index=row_index, col_index=col_index:
                                                                    self.change_button_color("black", self.marking_color, row_index, col_index, "#333333", False))
            self.autotracking_labels[(row_index, col_index)] = self.check_names[row_index*self.row_size + col_index][:-5]

    self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_image)
```

I have tried just about every frame/grid packing combination I could find and nothing seems to reduce the lag on the resizing. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Every time you resize the window, you reload every single image from disk - that's probably what takes the most time.  Are any of the images used multiple times?  If so, there would be room for improvement by sharing such images between widgets, loading and resizing them only once.  If not, or if that's not enough of a speed-up, I'd suggest loading the images *once*, keeping them in memory, and just resize them as needed.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for the detailed response! I did forget to mention that the images are ImageTk.PhotoImages so they don't have the option to be resized without recreating them. Should I just try to switch them to normal images?

Comment: Although now that I think about it your last suggestion seems like it would work. Thank you!

Comment: You're loading the images in 3 steps: as an `Image`, then resized, then converted to a `PhotoImage`.  You can't avoid that last step if you intend to use them with Tkinter.  I'm saying keep the original `Image` around, so that you can resize and reconvert it when needed - that should be substantially faster than reloading.

Comment: Yep I realized that a moment after I typed it. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: This managed to speed it up, but it still has a lot of lag relative to any other window. It's at least not unusable now so I'll be satisfied with it for now.